# Render HTML in div tag in MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a field in db which stores html and i want to render that html on userside. but i am unable to do so. when i tried to put html in div tag or paragraph tag then i get simply html text. here is my code which i tried

```
<%: HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlDecode(Model.HomePageText) %>
```

and i get following result by using this (HTML appears as text)

```
<p> </p> <p style="color: rgb(88, 100, 109); font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 16px; background-position: -1px -350px; "> Enter custom CSS code into the box below to further customize your mobile site.</p>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `Html.Raw` to output your HTML:

```
<div>@Html.Raw(Model.HomePageText)</div>
```

Comment: @AnkushJain Please consider Rewarding Marek by marking his answer as accepted if he helped solve your problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Html.Raw(Model.HomePageText)`, assuming you're certain there won't be any issues (script injection, harmful html etc).